# How to connect to Node API docker container from Angular Nginx container

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I am currently working on an angular app using Rest API (Express, Nodejs) and Postgresql. Everything worked well when hosted on my local machine. After testing, I moved the images to Ubuntu server so the app can be hosted on an external port. I am able to access the angular frontend using the https://server-external-ip:80 but when trying to login, Nginx is not connecting to NodeApi. Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.0' 

services:

  db:
    image: postgres:9.6-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: myDb
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: myPwd

    ports:
    - 5432:5432
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
    - my-network

  backend: # name of the second service
   image: myId/mynodeapi
   ports:
   - 3000:3000
   environment:
    POSTGRES_DB: myDb
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: myPwd
    POSTGRES_PORT: 5432
    POSTGRES_HOST: db
   depends_on:
   - db
   networks:
   - my-network

   command: bash -c "sleep 20 && node server.js"

  myapp:
    image: myId/myangularapp
    ports:
    - "80:80"
    depends_on:
    - backend
    networks:
    - my-network

networks:
    my-network:
```

I am not sure what the apiUrl should be?  I have tried the following and nothing worked:

1. apiUrl: "http://backend:3000/api"
2. apiUrl: "http://server-external-ip:3000/api"
3. apiUrl: "http://server-internal-ip:3000/api"
4. apiUrl: "http://localhost:3000/api"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use the `docker-compose` service as a `DNS`. It seems you've several docker hosts/ports available, there are the following in your docker-compose structure:

- db:5432
- http://backend:3000
- http://myapp

Make sure to use `db` as `POSTGRES_DB` in the environment part for `backend` service.

Take a look to my [repo](https://github.com/hugolesta/multi-docker), I think is the best way to learn how a similar project works and  how to build several apps with `nginx`, you also can check my `docker-compose.yml`, it uses several services and are proxied using `nginx` and are worked together.

On this [link](https://github.com/hugolesta/multi-docker/blob/master/nginx/default.conf) you’ll find a `nginx/default.conf` file and it contains several `nginx` upstream configuration please take a look at how I used docker-compose service references there as `hosts`.

Inside the [client/](https://github.com/hugolesta/multi-docker/tree/master/client) directory, I also have another `nginx` as a web server of a react.js project.

On [server/](https://github.com/hugolesta/multi-docker/tree/master/server) directory, it has a Node.js API, It connects to Redis and Postgres SQL database also built from docker-compose.yml.

If you need set or redirect traffic to /api you can use some `ngnix` config like [this](https://github.com/hugolesta/multi-docker/blob/master/nginx/default.conf#L23)

I think this use case can be useful for you and other users!

Comment: Thanks @Hugo Lesta.  I will try this and let you know.

Comment: Nice, good luck, let me know if you need more assistance

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  It is a new concept for me so  I read thru articles before trying it out but it worked.  Thank you so much for your detailed explanation.  One question though - I have tested it on couple of machines by accessing the app via localhost but how can I access it using http://myapp?  I have tried this and it did not work.
 `server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  myapp;
    location / {
         proxy_pass http://myapp;
    }
    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://backend:3000;
    }
} `

Comment: Hello :), Have you checked the container status? Are all of them up and running? Have you tried to run http://localhost in your browser? If my previous answer was useful, please mark as solved, perhaps it helps other users.

Comment: Yes they are all up and running.  It works fine on my localhost and also, on localhost of another computer.  Just wondering how to configure if I have to run outside of localhost.

Comment: If you host this solution in a virtual machine and run these containers, you’ll bind those ports in that machine, this means that you also could have a load balancer pointing to port 80 and it will work well, if just you also can set up DNS records pointing to this machine, it will work as well. If you just want to create a simple host called myapp, you should set up your internal host file to achieve that. I hope it may help you